# Is there any way to deploy/run Java WAR files on Apache Server (not Tomcat)?

Tags: apache, deployment, war

I'm running an Apache 2.4.3 server.  I've tried Googling for solutions to this, but everything just brings up Apache Tomcat servers.  Unfortunately, the solutions for Tomcat don't seem to be portable, since I can't find any `webapps` directory, any `server.xml`, or the like.

So is there some method I can use to get a WAR file running on a regular Apache server?  Or do I have to switch servers?

Comment: By "Apache server" do you mean httpd?

Comment: @James I assume so.  I'm using a packaged "XAMPP" distribution which includes lots of things.  Under the includes, it just says "Apache [version number]".  http://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Apache httpd doesn't directly know anything about .war files (or J2EE applications in general), so you'll need to connect it to a Servlet container somehow.  There are several ways, e.g. via the (direct) Apache Tomcat Connector, or by indirectly running a Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat or Jetty) and forwarding/proxying to it from Apache.